# how to troubleshoot asp sub routine code

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I've been tasked to troubleshoot the following error. I have no experience with asp and looking for some guidance. Here's the error:

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd' 
>       Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation   requires a current record. 
>       /include/asp/classTools.asp, line 700

I found this class and opened it up to the offending line and surround sub routine and have this:

```vb
Private Sub LookUpTheCurrentUsersEmployeeID_AndName()
    Dim User
    User = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
    User = Right(User, (Len(User) - InStrRev(User,"\") ) )
    Execute_SQL("SELECT User_ID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr FROM SupportDesk WHERE UserName = '" & User & "'")
    If xRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
        EmployeeID_OfCurrentUser = 0
        EmployeeFullName = User
        EmployeeEmailAddress = "unknownEmailAddress"
    Else
        EmployeeID_OfCurrentUser = xRS("User_ID")
        EmployeeFullName = xRS("FirstName") & " " & xRS("LastName")
        EmployeeEmailAddress = xRS("EmailAddr")
    End If
    bLookedUpTheID_AndName = True
End Sub
```

I looked in the table Support and found no null records. What else should I look at?
Is the logic for this sub routine sound?

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` inside your code?

Comment: What does `Execute_SQL()` do exactly? If it returns the `xRS` object I would say it's returning an empty `ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: @Alireza If they had `On Error Resume Next` they would never see this error in the first place.

Comment: @Alireza Yes it's Classic ASP the `Private Sub` is because it's a private method inside a Class.

Comment: @Lankymart - ok, that's a good place to start. It looks like there's a number of places that `xRS` is used and so is Execute_SQL - querying different fields, i think its building a dataset and perhaps one of these instances is empty.

Comment: The query in question that is generating the empty `ADODB.Recordset` object is going to be `"SELECT User_ID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr FROM SupportDesk WHERE UserName = '" & User & "'"` so I would attempt to `Response.Write "SELECT User_ID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr FROM SupportDesk WHERE UserName = '" & User & "'"` to screen and try and run that SQL statement in the DBMS to see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test

```
If xRS.EOF Then
```

instead of

```
If xRS.RecordCount = 0 Then
```

because .[Recordcount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be -1 for "no count available" if the recordset is forwards only.

Evidence:

```
>> Set c = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
>> c.Open "dsn=NWind"
>> Set r = c.Execute("Select * From Employees Where EmployeeId=1")
>> WScript.Echo r.Recordcount, r("EmployeeId")
>> Set r = c.Execute("Select * From Employees Where EmployeeId=0")
>> WScript.Echo r.Recordcount
>> WScript.Echo r("EmployeeId")
>>
-1 1 <------- non-empty rs; recordcount <> 0!
-1   <------- empty rs; recordcount <> 0! ---------> oramel's error:
Error Number:       -2147352571
Error Description:  Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.
```

The given error is raised because of the attempt to access a field of an empty recordset; the problem is not detected because the comparison against 0.

**Update wrt comments:**

*Assumptions:*

1. Execute_SQL() sets xRS to the recordset resulting from the passed in
   SOL statement.
2. SupportDesk.UserName is unique.
3. The error "EOF or BOF" is thrown in the line
   `EmployeeID_OfCurrentUser = xRS("User_ID")` (because xRS is empty -
   see Evidence)
4. Sub LookUpTheCurrentUsersEmployeeID_AndName() is called in contexts
   like

wtf

```
LookUpTheCurrentUsersEmployeeID_AndName
If 0 = EmployeeID_OfCurrentUser Then
   ' handle Employee not found
Else
   ' handle Employee found
End If
```

*Facts:*

1. If you just CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") or if you try to
   .Execute/.Open using a faulty SQL statement and hide this problem by
   using OERN, an attempt to access its .RecordCount results in a 3704
   "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed." error.
2. The error line will be reached if and only if .RecordCount is not
   equal to 0.

*Conclusion:*

The error line will be reached if .RecordCount is

- 1 (assumption 2). In that case the fields are accessible; there is no
  error.
- -1 **and EOF**: The error is thrown because the recordset is empty (There is no such UserName in your database)
- -1 **and Not EOF**: no error is thrown bcause the recordset is not empty (There is such a UserName in your database)

*Remedy:*

Check for xRS.EOF to make sure you have a non-empty recordset when you access its fields
in the Else clause.

Despite Lankymart's first doubt, queries for users not (yet) in your database will be handled correctly, if assumption 4 holds.

Despite Lankymart's second doubt, .RecordCount being always -1 is harmless, because instead of .RecordCount the really relevant pre-condition "is xRS.EOF" guards the access to the fields of the recordset.

*Possible cause:*

Changes to your Database/Connection configuration made Forward Cursors the default.

*Voodoo:*

You 'looked in the table Support' but your SQL refers to table SupportDesk. Maybe your
problem is caused by mixing table names.

Comment: That doesn't tackle if it **is** always expecting to have a result. I agree there should be a check for `If Not xRS.EOF Then` but they would have to handle the outcome, bearing in mind this is located inside a Class. Plus we don't know yet what `Execute_SQL()` actually does, I can guess but then what's the point in guessing.

Comment: There's a number of Execute_SQL() statements within this class. I'm assuming I need to find out from the user what exactly they were doing and trace to see which sql statement could have been used.

Comment: @oramel No not at all, it tells you the line in `classTools.asp` that is triggering the error (line 700). If the code in the question is from line 700 then the offending sql statement is `"SELECT User_ID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddr FROM SupportDesk WHERE UserName = '" & User & "'"` as it's that `Execute_SQL()` call that is returning an empty `ADODB.Recordset`. I did try to explain this in my comment above in the question.

Comment: The example in your answer isn't very clear because you've used a forward-only cursor, so the `RecordCount` is always `-1` regardless of whether the `ADODB.Recordset` is empty or not. This may confuse the OP even further.

Comment: Nice effort! +1 Although there not doubts I was just pointing out that from one of your [initial draft answers](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25041865/2) it wasn't clear and could confuse the OP. I've been doing this long enough to know that you should always check `EOF` first, I never rely on `RecordCount` primarily because I convert `ADODB.Recordset` to an Array and use `UBound()` instead.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your input. We did find an issue with the user's UserName not being in the database.